# Rasbperry pi 5 Camera ZWO ASI715MC

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi-os, video-input

I have been trying to solve the problem with connecting ZWO ASI715MC cameras via USB for a long time. The system does not see the device as dev/video0. Information I found about the camera connected to the system:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[ 2729.008542] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo

I managed to find such data above related to the camera. Does anyone have an idea how to solve the problem? The Rasbperry OS Debian 64-bit system, if it matters, boots via a pendrive